# How can I persist a POJO with transactions, versioning, history, and hierarchy - using no-schema?

Tags: java, nosql, persistence, pojo

I am writing a system where I want to be able to persist various "Job Templates" to some kind of datastore.  In our system, the Templates are domain objects which contain descriptions of how to do various mathematical calculations.

I would like to have some kind of robust store for these Template POJOs - preferably some kind of shared/remote repository so that multiple systems could access, and potentially modify, the Templates.

I am slightly overwhelmed by the number of NoSQL, graph-, document- and object-databases out there, and was hoping to get some guidance from people who've done this before!

In my ideal world, this would be a magical no-schema datastore, so that any Template object could be written out to it with a simple method call, and then retrieved again later.  I would ideally like to have the following features -

1)  Versioning - so I can "overwrite" a previous POJO, and track the version changes
2)  History - so I can go back (time machine style) and retrieve prior versions
3)  Transactions - so everything is consistent and bulletproof
4)  Hierarchy - so I can group POJOs, and find them by path, etc

Some options appear to include Jackrabbit OCM, OrientDB, CouchDB. Also there is JDO (DataNucleus) vs JPA. Could anyone share any insights to cut through the fog of too much choice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What an open question!

I use Jackrabbit, which fulfills all your needs and is very easy to get up and running. You can perform XPATH queries as well as several other types. Not very good on documentation but the JCR docs are usually enough to get by. There are other JCR implementations. You might want to consider them/find benchmarks if you intend on pushing the limits :)

Comment: Thanks TedTrippin - sorry it as such a wide ranging question!